# Running multiple functions in Python where both are infinite loops and one is an input loop

Tags: python, loops, concurrency, multiprocessing

Suppose I have two functions

```
def ticker():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        time.sleep(60)

def main():
    while True:
        message = input("> ")
        parse_data(message)
```

And I have this code to run it concurrently

```
from multiprocessing import Process
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process(target=ticker).start()
    Process(target=main).start()
```

I experience an EoF error in main() on input("> "). If I catch this error in a try / except like so:

```
try:
    message = input("> ")
except EOFError:
    continue
```

This will just continually print "> " to the screen. If I try it this way

```
try:
    message = input("> ")
except EOFError:
    main()
```

where main() is the function which contains this code, it'll just continually error.

There appears to be no errors in the ticker() function. The only errors appear to be coming from my lack of understanding of concurrency in Python and a lack of google-results for this query.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just put the loop that's in the main function under `if __name__ == "__main__":` rather than in its own function